# What is the fastest way to add a poly frame to a window hole?

Tags: modeling

I am proceeding like this: first I select the hole external edges.
[image]

And I make a face out of them:
[image: And I make a face out of them:]

Then I duplicate the face in the Y axis, and delete the old one (I don't know how to detach the new face from the main object):
[image]

Then I extrude:
[image]

Then I extrude again all faces, so to inflate the box by the right amount:
[image]

Then I delete the back face:
[image]

Then I bring the open box to intersect the wall:
[image]

Then I make FACE - INTERSECT (BOOLEAN):
[image]

Then I merge the exceeding vertexes and assign the new material:
[image]

Et voilá: frame in the wall.

I am sure this is a stupidly long and convoluted process and that there's a quick command to do this.
Please tell me it's true.

Edit: a little bit faster.
Take the 4 sides of the window, duplicate and move locally in axis, extrude along normals with negative value, delete faces in excess, then move the 4 polygons back into the wall and do the intersect boolean.
It's a bit faster. Still makes no sense.

Comment: All of that can be easier by using *inset*.

Comment: Ehm no, I know the command INSET... but the windows need to be that dimension. I need to put the frame to the external of the existing hole. That's the whole point of this post.

Comment: The inset tool has an "outset" option, did you try that?

Comment: @PolyMad  The structure of your question may be a little confusing for some readers, may I suggest something like "I have this  > I want this > I am doing this" somewhere?

Comment: As @susu points out, there is an _outset_ option. But I think it's fair to suggest, when modeling to reference, if you want to save time and get clean results, planning  is  _the_ most important step. ( You would raise an eyebrow if you saw a builder taking a jackhammer to a wall to fit a wooden window-frame.. :)  )

Comment: Didn't see that outset option, going to check it immediately! I'm not yet used to the options popping up after calling the function, sorry for noooobnesss!

Comment: @Timaroberts you want me to put all that thing in the question title??? Or in the body? I think the body is pretty much explanatory the way it is.  
The "I am doing this" thing is only there to show what I was using as a temporary solution: it wouldn't help anyone in doing something the right way, but it's perfect to understand what is the need. I could have avoided that completely by presenting only the initial picture and the final picture.

Answer (score 11):

Use the *Inset* tool in *Outset mode*. Then extrude and delete the inner face.

Outset will create new faces around the selected face.

[image]

Avoid using booleans, they will create bad topology.

Comment: **This is king!**

Comment: **This is the king!**

Answer (score 3):

Quickest way I could think of is to bevel the edges.

Just select the edge loop, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and adjust the number of cuts to $2$, and the shape to $1$.

[image]

Eliminate the inner edge loop if undesirable.

Comment: **This** is king!

Comment: Not the best for this exact situation, but I learned **something!**